# Kill/Abort/Stop a Task created with Task.Factory.StartNew()

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, task

I have a situation where I'm having to use a Async method created for google drive (one that I did not make and I'm just using the API) that does NOT recognize or respond to the CancelationToken passed in.

*Note: This has nothing to do with blocking the main UI.  That is not the case here.  As I said above, this is an ASYNC method!  This is about not letting tasks go rouge and unaccounted for.  This is about killing dead tasks that will go no where and are running in the background.*

Because of this (as much as I don't like killing threads/processes forcefully) I'm going to be forced to manually kill it when my timeout is reached.

The Async method returns a Task<> that gets created.  So with that task, how do I kill it forcefully?  Do I need to get the PID first somehow?

### UPDATE:

By popular demand, here is an example of how the task is created...

```
private void TryToAuthenticate()
{
  //Cancel the task BEFORE it starts works fine
  //m_cancelTokSrc.Cancel();

  //Start task
  Task<UserCredential> task = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
    scopes,
    "user",
    m_cancelTokSrc.Token,
    new FileDataStore(m_CredentialFilePath, true))
    .ContinueWith((t) => AuthenticateCompleted(t));

  //Cancel the task AFTER it starts fails and does nothing
  //m_cancelTokSrc.Cancel();
}

private UserCredential AuthenticateCompleted(Task<UserCredential> task)
{
  UserCredential credentials = null;
  switch (task.Status)
  {
    case TaskStatus.Canceled:
      return null;
    case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
      credentials = task.Result;
      break;
  }

  return credentials;
}
```

Comment: Can you give more information about what this method does? Do you have to stop it from further processing or are you OK with just getting control back?

Comment: @YacoubMassad I have it running as an actual Async method, so no my UI is not hung up or anything like that.  It's just creating a task that could possibly NEVER end.  In this circumstance it opens the default browser and tries to get you to validate you google credentials.  If the user just closes the browser window the Task will run forever and not stop.

Comment: If the method it self is async, why are you using `Task.Factory.StartNew`? Can you show some code?

Comment: @YacoubMassad : done

Answer (score 2):

You can't kill it. You need to write the code in such a way that execution continues although that API method is still running. You can do that, for example, by saying `await Task.WhenAny(apiTask, cancellationToken)`.

Comment: I added another note on the question.  Like I said, it has nothing to do with the main UI being blocked.  This answer addresses a non-issue.

Comment: I'm not talking about the UI. You cannot kill that task, period. Cancellation is always cooperative in .NET and 1000s of questions before yours have hit the same basic problem. You're not the first one facing an unkillable task.; Instead, abandon it and continue doing what you wanted to do in case of timeout.

Comment: That seems very unclean.  What if the user starts that same task 100 times...  I will have 100 "tasks" running in the background.  Also, if your not talking about the UI when you said `You need to write the code in such a way that execution continues although that API method is still running.` then what are you talking about?  There is an example in the question that clearly shows me doing just that btw.

Comment: Right, good concern. You can't do anything about it. If the library implemented `while(true);` you are out of luck. That thread will never end.; I can't see why the current code would terminate in case the token is getting signaled(?). `task` will not complete because cancellation is defective.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Are you saying that you can't see why it would NOT terminate (the way I have it).  Or are you saying that your confused as to what I'm doing in the code?

Comment: Maybe you best bet is to raise a Github issue with the Google team. They probably are responsive. Or, you can fix this in the source code. Other BCL stuff has the same problem. For example you can't cancel a Socket.Accept call. The hack to do that is to close the socket. Maybe you can "close" something here and pull a similar trick.

Comment: Ahh!  Now that is creative thinking.  I wish I knew what that "socket" to close was.  ;)

Comment: I totally get what you are saying. The cancellation story is full of nasty surprises. *Everyone* has to cooperate. It's the same thing with async when you need low latency on the UI. One mistake and the UI is frozen. For example HttpWebRequest performs DNS synchronously, so if DNS does not respond the UI is frozen. Async and cancellation are hard.

Comment: Unless we are the ones writing the API.  ;)